# append property to serialized json string in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a class which i want to serialize

```
public class DesignEntity
{
    public string DesignName { get; set; }
    public string DesignID { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public string designDetails { get; set; }
}
```

property `designDetails` already contains serialized data so no need to serialized it again

```
DesignEntity designSessionEntity = null;
JavaScriptSerializer jSerializer = null;
string designJsonSession = "null";

designSessionEntity = new DesignEntity();
jSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

designSessionEntity = /* */ // Get Values via some method
designJsonSession = jSerializer.Serialize(designSessionEntity); 
// Now append designDetails to resultant string json
```

I want to append `designDetails` to `designJsonSession` after serialization is complete. How can i achieve the same ?

Comment: Deserialize, add and serialize again.

Comment: Show the initial format, and the desired result. It is pretty unclear what output format you want.

Comment: Why are u doing this: `string designJsonSession = "null";`? You can just do `string designJsonSession = null;`

Comment: @Sybren There is actually no need to assign `null` - it is default value. Moreover, there is no need to split declaration and assignment up :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I know there's no need to. But looking at his code he want's to assign `null`.

Comment: @Sybren Yeah, I know, you are right :) It was like complement. The comment was more for the OP, not for you.

Comment: that "null" was assigned because in client side while doing `JSON.parse("null")` it wont produce error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, add one more field to your `DesignEntity` class. Whose type is the contract class that `designDetails` json is serialized from.

```
public class DesignEntity
{
    public string DesignName { get; set; }
    public string DesignID { get; set; }
    /// new field
    public DesignDetailsObject DesignDetails { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public string designDetails { get; set; }
}
```

And then, get your object as usual, deserialize the json first into that new field, then serialize it.

```
var designSessionEntity = new DesignEntity();
var jSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

designSessionEntity = /// Get Values via some method

/// assign the design details with deserialized object
designSessionEntity.DesignDetails = jSerializer.Deserialize<DesignDetailsObject>(designSessionEntity.designDetails);

/// serialize it again
var designJsonSession = jSerializer.Serialize(designSessionEntity);
```

Voila!

**Update**

If you don't have access to the class that `designDetails` json is serialized from, then you have two options.

1. Try to deduce the class from the json structure and create the `DesignDetailsObject` yourself (Recommended).
2. Append the json string manually (I'll try to show you how if you need) - This method must be applied if the class is really heavy, and won't worth the work.

Code Snippet For option 2:

```
public string JsonAppender ( string targetJson, List<string> fields, object value )
{
    var insertIndex = 0;
    foreach ( var field in fields )
    {
        var _fieldDescriptor = field + "\":";
        insertIndex += targetJson.Substring(insertIndex).IndexOf(_fieldDescriptor) + _fieldDescriptor.Length;
    }

    var lengthOfDefaultVal = targetJson.Substring(insertIndex).IndexOf("\"") - 1;

    return targetJson.Substring(0, insertIndex) + "\"" + value + "\"" + targetJson.Substring(insertIndex + lengthOfDefaultVal);
}
```

Usage:

```
var fieldAppendedJson = JsonAppender(json, new List<string> { "designDetails " }, designSessionEntity.designDetails);
```

Comment: What is `DesignDetailsObject` ?

Comment: That is supposed to be the class that your json `designDetails` is serialized from at the first place.